# graphene-python doesn't recognize ´content_type´ field

Tags: python, django, graphene-python

I am making my first attempt to use ´graphene-python´, and I have been able to make it work so far, but I have found that ´graphene-python´ doesn't recognize **ForeignKey** fields that reference **ContentType** model.

This is my model:

```
class ReservationComponent(models.Model):
    reservation = models.ForeignKey(Reservation, on_delete=models.PROTECT, related_name='components', verbose_name=_("Reservation"))
    dertour_bk = models.CharField(null=True, blank=True, max_length=15, verbose_name=_("Dertour Bk"))
    day = models.DateField(verbose_name=_('Day'))
    content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    content_object = GenericForeignKey('content_type', 'object_id')
    comment = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True, verbose_name=_("Comment"))
    is_invoiced = models.BooleanField(default=False, verbose_name=_("Is Invoiced"))
```

This is my **schemas.py**:

```
import graphene
from graphene_django.types import DjangoObjectType
from ReservationsManagerApp.models import Reservation, ReservationComponent
from InvoicesManagerApp.models import Invoice, InvoiceEntry, InvoiceEntryComponent
from PaymentsManagerApp.models import Payment, PaymentReservationComponent

class ReservationType(DjangoObjectType):
    class Meta:
        model = Reservation

class ReservationComponentType(DjangoObjectType):
    class Meta:
        model = ReservationComponent

class InvoiceType(DjangoObjectType):
    class Meta:
        model = Invoice

class InvoiceEntryType(DjangoObjectType):
    class Meta:
        model = InvoiceEntry

class InvoiceEntryComponentType(DjangoObjectType):
    class Meta:
        model = InvoiceEntryComponent

class PaymentType(DjangoObjectType):
    class Meta:
        model = Payment

class PaymentReservationComponentType(DjangoObjectType):
    class Meta:
        model = PaymentReservationComponent

class  Query(object):
    all_reservations = graphene.List(ReservationType)
    all_reservation_components = graphene.List(ReservationComponentType)
    all_invoices = graphene.List(InvoiceType)
    all_invoice_components = graphene.List(InvoiceEntryType)
    all_invoice_entries_components = graphene.List(InvoiceEntryComponentType)
    all_payment = graphene.List(PaymentType)
    all_payment_reservation_components = graphene.List(PaymentReservationComponentType)

    def resolve_all_reservations(self, info, **kwargs):
        return Reservation.objects.all()

    def resolve_all_reservation_components(self, info, **kwargs):
        return ReservationComponent.objects.select_related('reservation').all()

    def resolve_all_invoice_entries_components(self, info, **kwargs):
        return InvoiceEntryComponent.objects.select_related('reservation_component').all()

    def resolve_all_payment_reservation_components(self, info, **kwargs):
        return PaymentReservationComponent.objects.select_related('reservation_component').all()
```

And, in this image, you can see that the field ´content_type´ of model ´ReservationComponent´ is not accepted by **graphene-python**, even when it exists in the model.

[image]

I don't know if I am missing any setting, or something.

Comment: You probably missing type for ContentType. Check https://docs.graphene-python.org/projects/django/en/latest/tutorial-plain/#defining-our-models

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because you do not have `DjangoObjectType` for django's `ContentType` model.

You can create it by,

```py
from graphene_django import DjangoObjectType
from django.contrib.contenttypes.models import ContentType

class ContentObjectType(DjangoObjectType):

    class Meta:
        model = ContentType
```

As per [documentation](https://docs.graphene-python.org/projects/django/en/latest/tutorial-plain/#hello-graphql-schema-and-object-types), you must create a type for each models subclassing `DjangoObjectType`

Comment: I don't know why someone downvoted this, but it's the right answer. 

I am guessing that the downvote is because OP wants to transparently handle all subtypes via magic but that's a whole other question if so.